# suitable name for a sequence which only grows at one end

Tags: c++, containers, sequence

A few times I use a restricted interface over a `vector` or another mutable sequence ( a sequence adapter) which only allows `push_back` and `clear`. It has some nice property such as, an iterator can be designed based on index which is always stable (like `stable_vector` but also has element contiguity) and hence can be stored without fear of invalidation unless it is cleared.

I want to use a adapter class instead of `vector` or another sequence directly to emphasize the interface (as well as to prevent any accidental mistake using unsupported operations such as `insert` , `erase` etc).

Is there any existing ADT which matches with this `append_only` sequence? Otherwise can anyone recommend a suitable name for this sequence adapter?

Comment: From your description [you mean a stack](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/stack.html).

Comment: This can not be stack as stack adt does not support any iteration over the elements while that is the key point here.

Comment: Nonsense, nothing prevents you from defining an iterator. **No** ADT is normally defined as having iterators, since iterators are a C++ specific detail.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: More importantly, the *typical* stack ADT doesn't support non-destructive access to elements other than the one at the top. So the ADT provides no means to do what C++ iterators do. Obviously you could define a different ADT, "stack with iteration". Depending which direction you want the iteration to go that might rule out certain implementations of a typical stack ADT. I'm thinking of a singly-linked list.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it about `std::stack` which does not support iteration. `std::stack` modeled over `BackInsertionSequence`, and may not be able to implement iteration from first to last over some containers (in can think of some `reverse_list` which most of the text books implement, in contrast with `std::forward_list` which can not be used for `std::stack`). Probably that is why stack has `push` and `pop` rather than `push_front` and `pop_front`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any existing ADT to do what you want. As for the name I would go with `PushOnlyVector` or something of the kind. In fact I also like the `append_only` in your question so you may also make use of it: `AppendOnlyVector`. And one last option: `GrowingArray`. I keep the `vector` or `array` as part of the name to emphasize you support index operation.